# How to hide UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c

HI,

I have listController, detailsController and editController. I need to hide UITabBarController for DetailsController only not for all other controllers.I used below code.

ListController.m

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

detailsController* detailViewController = [[detailsController alloc] init];

detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

But, my problem is in editController I am not getting UITabBarController at bottom.

But, I need to get TabBarController in editController.

Please any one help me to solve this.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

...have you a navigation controller?

If not, you can use

```
detailViewController.modalInPopover = YES;
detailViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
detailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

and you show it in fullscreen, hiding tabbar.

To dismiss it use:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

alberto.